# Errors when attempting to update team field values

Tags: azure-devops, sdk, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-server-2019

I'm getting any of multiple errors when I try to use the Client SDK to add an existing Area to an existing Team. Here's my code:

```vb
Using oTeamClient As TeamHttpClient = Utils.Connection.GetClient(Of TeamHttpClient)
  Using oWorkClient As WorkHttpClient = Utils.Connection.GetClient(Of WorkHttpClient)
    oValue = New TeamFieldValue With {.Value = Area.Path, .IncludeChildren = False}
    oTeams = oTeamClient.GetTeamsAsync(ProjectName).Result
    oTeam = oTeams.Single(Function(Team) Team.Name.StartsWith(ProjectName))
    oPatch = New TeamFieldValuesPatch With {.Values = {oValue}, .DefaultValue = $"{ProjectName}\{Area.Path}"}
    oContext = New TeamContext(ProjectName, oTeam.Name)

    Return oWorkClient.UpdateTeamFieldValuesAsync(oPatch, oContext).Result
  End Using
End Using
```

The problem is that I don't know what to use for `TeamFieldValuesPatch.DefaultValue`.

Here's what I've tried and the corresponding error message for each attempt:

- Nothing: "DefaultValue"
- Empty String: "VssServiceException: The default team field value must be one of this team's allowed team field values."
- Project Name: "VssServiceException: The default team field value must be one of this team's allowed team field values."
- Area Path: "VssServiceException: TF400499: You have not set your team field."
- Project Name + Area Path: "VssServiceException: The default team field value must be one of this team's allowed team field values."

Unfortunately, [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/teamfieldvalues/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#update-team-field-values.-example-1) provides no explanation of the validation rules for this property, nor any guidance on what value we should use. It *seems* to indicate Project Name + Area Path, but as we can see above that doesn't work.

There's [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/troubleshooting?view=azure-devops#error-tf400499), but it conflicts with the (obscure) hint in the documentation. There's [this](https://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/rfennell/2013/09/16/tf400499-you-have-not-set-your-team-field-when-trying-to-update-team-settings-via-the-tfs-api/), but I've verified that the Area exists before the update is attempted.

What value should I use for this property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above error `The default team field value must be one of this team's allowed team field values` means
the area path you defined in the `TeamFieldValuesPatch.DefaultValue` property must be included in the `TeamFieldValuesPatch.Values` property too.

If the area path defined for `DefaultValue` cannot be found in the `Values`. Above error will be thrown out. See below example in c#

```
 VssConnection _connection = new VssConnection(accountUri, new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, personalAccessToken));

 WorkHttpClient workClient = _connection.GetClient<WorkHttpClient>();
 TeamFieldValuesPatch patch = new TeamFieldValuesPatch();
 patch.DefaultValue = "Project\\DefaultAreaPath";
            
 List<TeamFieldValue> values = new List<TeamFieldValue> { 
   #defaultValue must be included in the values 
   new TeamFieldValue { Value = "Project\\DefaultAreaPath", IncludeChildren = false },
   new TeamFieldValue { Value = "Project\\OtherAreaPath", IncludeChildren = false }
 };
            
 patch.Values = values;
 TeamContext team = new TeamContext("Project", "Team");

 var res = workClient.UpdateTeamFieldValuesAsync(patch, team).Result;
```

Comment: Once again, inadequate documentation and misleading error messaging conspire to hinder productive development. OK, that worked. Thank you. FYI I also discovered via this exercise that using the GUI to include all of the root area path's sub-areas eliminates the requirement to add a new area to a team before using that area for a work item. So it could be said that this part of the effort ultimately was unnecessary. But it was a good learning experience nonetheless.

Comment: This error code is Unbelievable!